# Is specific way of importing submodules at all possible?

Tags: python, import, module, python-import, python-module

I am working in the following directory tree:

```
src/
    __init__.py
    train.py
    modules/
        __init__.py
        encoders/
            __init__.py
            rnn_encoder.py
```

My `pwd` is the top-level directory and my `__init__.py` files are all empty. I am executing `train.py`, which contains the following code snippet.

```
import modules

# RNNEncoder is a class in rnn_encoder.py
encoder = modules.encoders.rnn_encoder.RNNEncoder(**params)
```

When I execute `train.py`, I get an error saying that

`AttributeError: module 'modules' has no attribute 'encoders'`

I am wondering if there is any **clean** way to make this work. Note that I am not looking for alternative methods of importing, I am well-aware that this can be done in other ways. What I'd like to know is whether it is possible to keep the code in `train.py` as is while maintaining the given directory structure.

Comment: Are you allowed to modify the `__init__.py` files? If so: in `encoders/__init__.py` put the line `from . import rnn_encoder` at the top, and in `modules/__init__.py` put `from . import encoders` at the top, and that should work

Comment: `encoders` must be available in `modules/__init__.py`, you probably want something like `from . import encoders.rnn_encoder` in there

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy Awesome! If you write it as an answer, I will mark it as selected!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting an `__init__.py` file in a folder allows that folder to act as an import target, even when it's empty. The way you currently have things set up, the following should work:

```
from modules.encoders import rnn_encoder
encoder = rnn_encoder.RNNEncoder(**params)
```

Here, python treats `modules.encoders` as a filepath, essentially, and then tries to actually import the code inside `rnn_encoder`.

However, this won't work:

```
import modules
encoder = modules.encoders.rnn_encoder.RNNEncoder(**params)
```

The reason is that, when you do `import modules`, what python is doing behind the scenes is importing `__init__.py` from the `modules` folder, and nothing else. It doesn't run into an error, since `__init__.py` *exists*, but since it's empty it doesn't actually *do* much of anything.

You can put code in `__init__.py` to fill out your module's namespace and allow people to access that namespace from outside your module. To solve your problem, make the following changes:

> `modules/encoders/__init__.py`

```
from . import rnn_encoder
```

> `modules/__init__.py`

```
from . import encoders
```

This imports `rnn_encoder` and assigns it to the namespace of `encoders`, allowing you to import `encoders` and then access `encoders.rnn_encoder`. Same with `modules.encoders`, except a step upwards.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks!